# Is this type of question allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I recently asked a question on pets.stackexchange.com today and it was put on hold as off-topic. The question is [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4395/what-breed-of-cats-are-these).

If it were to be migrated to anime.stackexchange.com, would it be acceptable as an on-topic question?

I had specifically asked this question on pets.stackexchange.com for obvious reasons but was not sure whether I should have asked it on anime.stackexchange.com or pets.stackexchange.com

To sum up my question, are these types of questions acceptable on Anime and Manga.SE because for me it doesn't seem to be on-topic as I am asking a specific question related to pets or real-life animal breeds in particular.

Comment: Those look like generic breed of cats. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_cat) has a similar looking one as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is on topic here, but the right way to phrase it and what would constitute a good answer is a bit different from on Pets SE (if they allowed the question).

Here the best answer would be someone finding some canon source which states what breed the cats are. Barring that, we'd be stuck speculating based solely on appearances. Such an answer would not be very good in my opinion. It might be acceptable if the answerer stated that there is no canon answer *but* it looks like breed X, or if they found some support in the anime for their guess, but I'd probably downvote an answer which was not at least partially based on the original material. You should be careful how you phrase the question here. At the end of the day, it has to be a question about the anime, not about breeds of cats (the latter of which are not on-topic).

Personally, I very much doubt there is a canon answer to this, so I'd be tempted to downvote it as a bad question. However, I probably wouldn't close it if it were phrased appropriately for this site. If someone did come along and found a canon answer, or if you have a good reason to suspect their breeds are known canonically, then that might change my assessment of the quality of the question.

Comment: The reason it's not allowed on Pets.SE is probably because of the ambiguity of the animated medium. Sure they're calico cats, but calico cats are a breed. So aside from being able to tell the coloring, it's hard to distinguish the actual breed without a canonical reference or an image of what they were based on.

Comment: @Krazer As I understand it, even real pet identification questions are [at least highly discouraged](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/410) on Pets SE, if not off-topic. Being animated presumably makes it worse, but the question may well have been closed even if it had a photo rather than an anime screencap. In any case, I don't think that them not taking the question for their reasons means that we should accept it unconditionally.